# KeyboardInterrupt unpredictable in Python 2.7 under ipython, how can I make it *always* abort current evaluation?

Tags: python, ipython, abort, keyboardinterrupt

I'm writing python code to do numerical analysis, and I've been using ipython or ipython -pylab as my command line interface. I often run into situations where some code is taking for-freaking-ever to run, and I need to stop it. However, Ctrl-C is problematic; sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't do anything, and sometimes it quits the whole process (**very** annoying.) How can I make it so that hitting Ctrl-C *always always* works? It seems as if the times that it doesn't work are those where it is executing code in some other module.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running a background thread that is swallowing the signal, there is no real way of prohibiting that, compare http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf

Comment: Some of the stuff IPython 0.10.x does for -pylab will automatically run background threads (to allow GUI event loops to run). I think this should be improved in IPython 0.11, which is due for release within the next week or so.