# How to abort a python script, but stay in the ipython interface?

Tags: python, copy-paste, keyboardinterrupt

Sometimes while executing a python script or while executing some command, it takes a long time to complete and I would like to abort the script or command. When I use Ctrl-C, nothing happnes. And when I use Ctrl-Z, the whole ipython interface exits and all the saved variables in the workspace will be lost. Is there any way around, to just abort the code while staying in ipython?

I see a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510138/keyboardinterrupt-unpredictable-in-python-2-7-under-ipython-how-can-i-make-it) but not properly answered.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 terminal to run ipython

Comment: Why do you believe that is possible? You could compare it to a program that freezes, you cannot just unfreeze it without not closing it. If your program takes too long, maybe it would be better to optimize bottleneck code

Comment: What if there is loop which accidentally went into an infinite loop? In such cases we could terminate the execution of the program by pressing Ctrl-C in Matlab and Scilab. Why not in Python?